# Unable to get the value of an API key from a website

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the value of API key avaialable within headers from [this website](https://www.pinnacle.com/en/). The value of API key can be found using [this link](https://guest.api.arcadia.pinnacle.com/0.1/sports/33/markets/live/straight) within headers (once the page is reloaded).

In dev tools, I found the headers like the following where API key and value are present:

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: https://www.pinnacle.com/en/
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36
X-API-Key: CmX2KcMrXuFmNg6YFbmTxE0y9CIrOi0R
X-Device-UUID: 3a10d97d-5dc63d32-9b562999-2a023260
```

However, when I print the headers (using the second link), I get the following items except for that API key.

```
{'Date': 'Tue, 20 Aug 2019 03:53:47 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/problem+json', 'Content-Length': '119', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Set-Cookie': '__cfduid=d43bcbb47c4b830f22e994d7311c5f37d1566273227; expires=Wed, 19-Aug-20 03:53:47 GMT; path=/; domain=.pinnacle.com; HttpOnly', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Accept, Content-Type, X-API-Key, X-Device-UUID, X-Session, X-Language', 'Access-Control-Max-Age': '86400', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'CF-Cache-Status': 'MISS', 'Expect-CT': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '50916c15eb6ee03b-DFW'}
```

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://guest.api.arcadia.pinnacle.com/0.1/sports/33/markets/live/straight'

res = requests.get(link)
print(res.headers)
```

***How can I get the value of API key from that site?***

Comment: The first snippet you posted contains the `request` headers while the second has `response`.

Comment: I checked the response headers from the server. I did not see any X-API-Key or X-Device-UUID field..

Comment: That's what I am saying. Why would response headers contain the API keys? You are the one who is supposed to send those, in the request.

Comment: I got your point @Selcuk. I thought that API key might be within page source or script tag which I can parse using one requests and then again sent that key within another requests.

Comment: It is _possible_ that the page source has the API key stored somewhere, but it would still be sent to the (backend) server in the request header. It would be very unusual to find it in the response header.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just break down how 'requests' works.

When you say:

```
res = requests.get(link)
```

It means you're sending the API server a request - you're supposed to be providing the API key here. It isn't supposed to be something 'requests' receives after a request, instead it's supposed to be something requests *needs* to perform the request.